# How can i install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian Buster)?

Tags: opencv, raspbian-buster

I have tried many days to install OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian Buster but i couldn't get it done. The installation always works but when importing or using cv2 methods like cv2.imshow(), errors come up (see below).

Did somebody get OpenCV working on a Raspberry Pi 4 or has an idea on how to get it working? Thank you in advance for your help :-)!

---

**Error after installing OpenCV with pip:**

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

python
>>> import cv2

ImportError: libImath-2_2.so.12: cannot open shared object file: nu such file or directory
```

---

**Error after installing OpenCV with conda:**

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=4.1.0
conda install -c menpo opencv

python
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)
>>> cv2.imshow("Frame", img)

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /home/jhelmus/conda/conda-bld/opencv_1512174356192/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 605
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_video.py", line 113, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Frame", img_main)
cv2.error: /home/jhelmus/conda/conda-bld/opencv_1512174356192/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:605: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

---

**Error after installing OpenCV by compiling it**

I went through the compilation processes described in these two guides. These guides worked on my Raspberry Pi 3b, but not on my Raspberry Pi 4:

1. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/
2. https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

After the process from the `make` command reached almost the end, it could not link the openCV installation to the Python executable (neither the Python executable in my conda virtual environment `/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5`, nor the global Python3 executable `/usr/bin/python3`. The errors were somehow like "Permission denied: Could not access Python3.5". I used this cmake setting:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes \
    -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5 \
    -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
    -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

I once tried this cmake command with the `PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/python3`.

Thank you in advance for your help :-)!

Paul

Comment: Welcome.  What's wrong with `apt install python-opencv`?  It is not version 4?

Comment: Hi @goldilocks ,thanks for welcoming and your suggestion. I tried it and suddenly i could run cv2.imshow() in python2 but not in python3, do you know why? I also read that the python-opencv repository is older, outdated, and doesn’t include the opencv_contrib package and therefore people do not recommend installing OpenCV via apt-get because one will be missing features and be running an older, outdated version.

Comment: I was now able to link the OpenCV installation to my Python environments but when I import cv2, it leads to the error: ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I would favour the distro package unless there is a specific reason beyond "I want to use the latest one", i.e., "I *need* to use version X.x because that version includes something I cannot do without".  When I looked though the package  search (`apt search opencv | grep python`) I'm pretty sure I saw python 3 explicitly , but you may want to have a closer look through that.  I think the OCV version is 3.2.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **OpenCV** from the default Raspbian Repository. It is tested and fits best into the Raspbian distribution without errors (I hope :). On **Buster** you will find with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list python*opencv*
Listing... Done
python-opencv-apps/testing 1.12.0-2 all
python-opencv/testing 3.2.0+dfsg-6 armhf
python3-opencv-apps/testing 1.12.0-2 all
python3-opencv/testing 3.2.0+dfsg-6 armhf
rpi ~$
```

Just `sudo apt install python3-opencv` and it should do. With `apt show python3-opencv` you will find that `Version: 3.2.0+dfsg-6` is installed. If you like you can also install the additional apps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It now works finally after almost one week of trying.. Because of my little reputation on StackExchange i cannot upvote your answer but i marked it as the right solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just found this after posting an OpenCV issue with Raspbian Buster.
The op followed the same guide as I did (although I am using a Pi3) and installed python-opencv-contrib not the basic opencv package?

I have also installed python-opencv-contrib, but using the PIP guide and am using it in a virtual environment. OpenCV is 4.5.1, installing using apt will only give me version 3.2.0?