# How to install OpenVINO and open CV 3.4.X on Raspberry Pi 4 Buster

Tags: opencv, raspbian-buster

I have been trying to install OpenVINO on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Buster as the OS.

I have tried these:

https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html

https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

I have seen this post too [How can i install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian Buster)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100253/how-can-i-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4-raspbian-buster) but this installs a version too low and I need 3.4.X or above to have the DNN modules that work with the Movidius Neural Compute Stick 2.

OpenVINO has installed ok, however, I cannot install Open CV 3.4.X to run the Python example they have in the OpenVINO tutorial and I need the DNN modules from Open CV 3.4.X or greater to interact with the Movidius.

Please help!

Comment: What's the problem? Why you can't install OpenVINO?

Comment: @Ingo OpenVINO is fine (I think), but I cannot install Open CV 3.4.X to run the Python example they have in the OpenVINO tutorial.

Comment: Please add this information to the question. You can edit it.

Comment: @Ingo it has now been edited